# Objective C to Java : NSOperationQueue?

Tags: java, objective-c

I'm trying to understand Objective C code and I'm stuck in this line

Code:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

I understand that this line constructs a new instance of a class `NSOperationQueue`. But what does this instance of `NSOperationQueue` do? Can anyone explain that to me? As I am more familiar with Java, it would be very helpful if someone could suggest me an equivalent piece of code in Java.

Comment: I don't get it, do you want to do this `NSOperationQueue queue = new NSOperationQueue();`?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to understand what's NSOperationQueue  doing and which is the equivalent function in Java.As I know NSOperationQueue is defined in Objective C's library or something like that.It's not a function or method which I wrote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `NSOperationQueue` implements basically the same functionality as you can get from a `ThreadPoolExecutor` plus a `BlockingQueue` in Java.

That is it takes a collection of `NSOperation`s *(approximate to `Runnables`s in Java)* and executes then asynchronously.

With the added bonus that the operation queue tunes itself to the current run-time conditions.

Comment: How to handle dependencies between tasks in a `ThreadPoolExecutor`?

Answer (score 4):

Runnables cannot be configured to have dependencies on each other, which is an important feature that NSOperation has. User may have to write custom codes (may use Future.get(), BlockingQueue.take()) to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`NSOperationQueue`'s documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). Basically, it's a class that is designed to execute multiple `NSOperation`. These are somewhat similar to threads (and they are executed in a background thread by `NSOperationQueue`).

Here's some more reading, if you need more details: [short tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html) and [full documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).

Comment: So basically this piece of code defines a new thread which is running in the background?

Comment: Not exactly: it defines a "runner" of abstract "operations", which are run in a background thread. A queue does nothing except running the actual operations, where the real work is done.

Comment: You can also add more complex behaviors like giving operations dependencies (other operations that must execute before them) among other things.

Comment: @Bombastic - Not necessarily *a thread*, an operation queue can and will run it's operation in parallel on several threads distributed on available CPU cores to optimize for the current work load.